# TinyMCE - Apply background color as block element, not span

Tags: tinymce

At the moment, TinyMCE background color button changes the color of a span. How do I apply the color as a block element (e.g. h1) instead of a `<span>` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a class to your block elements using the style dropdown.
The class you assign included the background color.

You have to make sure that the content_css setting of tinymce directs to a css file containing the css specification of the class you assign.